# SQL Query Result as JSON

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I am trying to get the result of the query as JSON.
My idea is to get all items of the menu inside each category
The JSON that I need is like this:

```
{
  "menu": {
      "category": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "description": "Category 1 Description",
            "items" : [
                {
                  "id" : 1,
                  "item_name" : "Item name 1",
                  "price": 200
                },
                {
                  "id": 2,
                  "item_name" : "Item name 1",
                  "price": 200 
                }
              ]
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "Category 1 Description",
            "items": [
                {
                  "id": 1,
                  "item_name" : "Item name 1",
                  "price": 200
                },
                {
                  "id": 2,
                  "item_name" : "Item name 1",
                  "price": 200
                },
                {
                  "id": 3,
                  "item_name" : "Item name 1",
                  "price": 200
                }
              ]
          }
        ]
  }
}
```

SQL Fiddle image: [SQL Fiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdxAJ.png)
The table that I got actually:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for menu_category
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `menu_category`;
CREATE TABLE `menu_category` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for menu_items
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `menu_items`;
CREATE TABLE `menu_items` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_category` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `small_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

I have already tried few queries but without success.
How can I write the query to get the JSON like the one that I posted?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you cannot do that in query, you have to convert it in the code itself

Comment: SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('menu', JSON_ARRAY('id', menu_category.id, 'description', menu_category.description, JSON_ARRAY('items', menu_items.item_name)))) from menu_category
INNER JOIN menu_items ON menu_category.id = menu_items.id_category GROUP BY menu_category.id
I have tried something like that

Comment: the end result will still be an array

Comment: if you can provide in SQL fiddle it will be easy to provide solution

Comment: I have added the SQL Fiddle Scheme inside the post

Comment: Sorry, @MicheleZotti, fiddle is not a picture. Please provide SQL code includes `INSERT INTO` statement on one of SQL fiddle services like https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=440f54b526b9052944c01f4a3dd007e5&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=10cd1e9337c773aa626b8c97945fc866&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For get desired result you can use [JSON_OBJECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object) and [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) functions like:

```
SELECT
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'id', `mc`.`id`,
      'description', `mc`.`description`,
      'items', 
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(
          JSON_OBJECT(
            'id', `mi`.`id`,
            'item_name', `mi`.`item_name`,
            'price', `mi`.`price`
          )
        )
) `menu`
FROM `menu_category` `mc` 
JOIN `menu_items` `mi` ON `mi`.`id_category` = `mc`.`id`
GROUP BY `mc`.`id`;
```

The query returns next result:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "description": "Category 1 Description",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "price": 100.00,
      "item_name": "Item 1 name"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "price": 100.00,
      "item_name": "Item 2 name"
    }
  ]
}
```

For add anothe data to JSON you can modify the query [here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=dbc288f5fbf18a6647a3029957c3aa4e&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80).

Comment: If I run the query on SQL  I get the JSON in this way and not like your post:
https://paste2.org/4kdm769N

Comment: Sorry.  I forgot to change `JSON_ARRAY` to `JSON_OBJECT`. Fixed now. Try it again